# How to install django-cms without error on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms

There are many errors with django-cms installation, and I tried the installation steps in the following link on github

[Step 1 - initial setup](https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial/)

and I got many fail installation for example:

1. Pillow is not compiled with JPEG Support
2. django cms pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Error while installing
   requirements. Check
3. pip log file for error details.

please I need help to illustrate these common problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I installing django-cms on Ubuntu14.04 have tried resolved many errors still not working allways say Pillow not complete installed as well south.

Finally found a link which is install django-cms on ubuntu13 have following step by step only removed some lines because I have already installed now all working :)
I follow the steps one by one here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-install-django-cms-on-a-debian-7-or-ubuntu-13-vps

Start:

1. mkdir myproject && cd myproject
2. sudo aptitude update
3. sudo aptitude upgrade
4. sudo aptitude install libpg-dev python-dev libpeg-dev libpng-dev

   Notce: if you not use sudo it will not run in the website above the owner has not used sudo
5. sudo pip install curl
   if you use bootstrap:
6. curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python -
7. curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python -
8. export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

   I have already installed virtualenv but if you need it not just follow:
9. pip install virtualenv
10. sudo pip install https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tarball/1.9.X
11. virtualenv env
12. source env/bin/activate
13. (env)$ cd env
14. (env)$ pip install pillow
15. (env)$ pip install south

    For Database is your choice
16. (env)$ pip install psycopg2
17. (env)$ sudo pip install django-cms

Notice: I have mention above somewhere I haven't used sudo, type as it is if not working then use sudo, I am also new with django-cms have installed in all three version ubuntu 10.04, 12.04 and 14.04.
I am not an expert in django but spend lots of times until reach to my point.

Best of luck

(

```
env)dilshad@DilVB:~/Desktop/sample/env$ sudo pip install django-cms
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-cms in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
(env)dilshad@DilVB:~/Desktop/sample/env$ sudo djangocms -p . mysite
Database configuration (in URL format) [default sqlite://localhost/project.db]: 
django CMS version (choices: 2.4, 3.0, stable, develop) [default stable]: 
Django version (choices: 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, stable) [default stable]: 1.6
Activate Django I18N / L10N setting (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Install and configure reversion support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Languages to enable. Option can be provided multiple times, or as a comma separated list. Only language codes supported by Django can be used here: en
Optional default time zone [default America/Chicago]: 
Activate Django timezone support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Activate CMS permission management (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Use Twitter Bootstrap Theme (choices: yes, no) [default no]: 
Use custom template set [default no]: 
Load a starting page with examples after installation. Choose "no" if you use a custom template set. (choices: yes, no) [default no]: yes
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table djangocms_text_ckeditor_text
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table django_site
Creating table cms_usersettings
Creating table cms_placeholder
Creating table cms_cmsplugin
Creating table cms_page_placeholders
Creating table cms_page
Creating table cms_globalpagepermission_sites
Creating table cms_globalpagepermission
Creating table cms_pagepermission
Creating table cms_pageuser
Creating table cms_pageusergroup
Creating table cms_title
Creating table cms_placeholderreference
Creating table cms_staticplaceholder
Creating table cms_aliaspluginmodel
Creating table menus_cachekey
Creating table south_migrationhistory
Creating table djangocms_style_style
Creating table djangocms_column_multicolumns
Creating table djangocms_column_column
Creating table djangocms_file_file
Creating table djangocms_flash_flash
Creating table djangocms_googlemap_googlemap
Creating table djangocms_inherit_inheritpageplaceholder
Creating table djangocms_link_link
Creating table djangocms_picture_picture
Creating table djangocms_teaser_teaser
Creating table djangocms_video_video
Creating table reversion_revision
Creating table reversion_version
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > djangocms_admin_style
 > djangocms_text_ckeditor
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.sitemaps
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.messages
 > cms
 > mptt
 > menus
 > south
 > sekizai
 > djangocms_style
 > djangocms_column
 > djangocms_file
 > djangocms_flash
 > djangocms_googlemap
 > djangocms_inherit
 > djangocms_link
 > djangocms_picture
 > djangocms_teaser
 > djangocms_video
 > reversion

Not synced (use migrations):
 - 
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
Running migrations for djangocms_text_ckeditor:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_rename_plugin.
 > cms:0001_initial
   (faked)
 > djangocms_text_ckeditor:0001_initial
   (faked)
 > djangocms_text_ckeditor:0002_rename_plugin
   (faked)
Running migrations for cms:
 - Migrating forwards to 0069_static_placeholder_permissions.
 > cms:0002_auto_start
   (faked)
 > cms:0003_remove_placeholder
   (faked)
 > cms:0004_textobjects
   (faked)
 > cms:0005_mptt_added_to_plugins
   (faked)
 > cms:0006_apphook
   (faked)
 > cms:0007_apphook_longer
   (faked)
 > cms:0008_redirects
   (faked)
 > cms:0009_added_meta_fields
   (faked)
 > cms:0010_5char_language
   (faked)
 > cms:0011_title_overwrites
   (faked)
 > cms:0012_publisher
   (faked)
 > cms:0013_site_copy
   (faked)
 > cms:0014_sites_removed
   (faked)
 > cms:0015_modified_by_added
   (faked)
 > cms:0016_author_copy
   (faked)
 > cms:0017_author_removed
   (faked)
 > cms:0018_site_permissions
   (faked)
 > cms:0019_public_table_renames
   (faked)
 > cms:0020_advanced_permissions
   (faked)
 > cms:0021_publisher2
   (faked)
 > cms:0022_login_required_added
   (faked)
 > cms:0023_plugin_table_naming_function_changed
   (faked)
 > cms:0024_added_placeholder_model
   (faked)
 > cms:0025_placeholder_migration
   (faked)
 > cms:0026_finish_placeholder_migration
   (faked)
 > cms:0027_added_width_to_placeholder
   (faked)
 > cms:0028_limit_visibility_in_menu_step1of3
   (faked)
 > cms:0029_limit_visibility_in_menu_step2of3_data
   (faked)
 > cms:0030_limit_visibility_in_menu_step3of3
   (faked)
 > cms:0031_improved_language_code_support
   (faked)
 > cms:0032_auto__del_field_cmsplugin_publisher_public__del_field_cmsplugin_publis
   (faked)
 > cms:0033_auto__del_field_title_publisher_is_draft__del_field_title_publisher_st
   (faked)
 > cms:0034_auto__chg_field_title_language__chg_field_cmsplugin_language__add_fiel
   (faked)
 > cms:0035_auto__add_field_globalpagepermission_can_view__add_field_pagepermissio
   (faked)
 > cms:0036_auto__add_field_cmsplugin_changed_date
   (faked)
 > cms:0037_auto__del_pagemoderator__del_field_globalpagepermission_can_moderate__
   (faked)
 > cms:0038_publish_page_permission
   (faked)
 > cms:0039_auto__del_field_page_moderator_state
   (faked)
 > cms:0040_auto__del_field_title_meta_keywords__chg_field_title_meta_description
   (faked)
 > cms:0041_auto__add_usersettings
   (faked)
 > cms:0042_auto__del_field_title_meta_keywords__chg_field_title_meta_description_
   (faked)
 > cms:0043_auto__add_field_usersettings_clipboard
   (faked)
 > cms:0044_killsettings
   (faked)
 > cms:0045_auto__add_field_page_application_urls
   (faked)
 > cms:0046_move_apphooks
   (faked)
 > cms:0047_auto__del_field_title_application_urls
   (faked)
 > cms:0048_auto__add_field_page_application_namespace__add_unique_page_publisher_
   (faked)
 > cms:0049_auto__add_field_page_is_home
   (faked)
 > cms:0050_save_home
   (faked)
 > cms:0051_auto__add_placeholderreference
   (faked)
 > cms:0051_fix_content_type
   (faked)
 > cms:0052_auto__add_placeholderreference__add_staticplaceholder__add_field_page_
   (faked)
 > cms:0053_auto__add_field_title_published__add_field_title_publisher_is_draft__a
   (faked)
 > cms:0054_new_publisher_data
   (faked)
 > cms:0055_auto__del_field_page_publisher_state__del_field_page_published
   (faked)
 > cms:0056_auto__del_field_page_published_languages
   (faked)
 > cms:0057_fix_values
   (faked)
 > cms:0058_placeholderref_table_rename
   (faked)
 > cms:0059_auto__del_pagemoderatorstate
   (faked)
 > cms:0060_auto__add_field_page_xframe_options
   (faked)
 > cms:0061_revers_id_unique
   (faked)
 > cms:0062_auto__add_field_staticplaceholder_site__del_unique_staticplaceholder_c
   (faked)
 > cms:0063_auto__chg_field_staticplaceholder_site
   (faked)
 > cms:0064_staticplaceholder_site_change
   (faked)
 > cms:0065_auto__add_unique_usersettings_user
   (faked)
 > cms:0066_auto__add_aliaspluginmodel
   (faked)
 > cms:0067_auto__add_field_aliaspluginmodel_alias_placeholder__chg_field_aliasplu
   (faked)
 > cms:0068_auto__chg_field_placeholder_slot
   (faked)
 > cms:0069_static_placeholder_permissions
   (faked)
Running migrations for menus:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > menus:0001_initial
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_style:
 - Migrating forwards to 0004_plugin_rename.
 > djangocms_style:0001_initial
   (faked)
 > djangocms_style:0002_auto__add_field_style_padding_left__add_field_style_padding_right__add
   (faked)
 > djangocms_style:0003_auto__add_field_style_tag_type__add_field_style_additional_classes
   (faked)
 > djangocms_style:0004_plugin_rename
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_column:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_plugin_rename.
 > djangocms_column:0001_initial
   (faked)
 > djangocms_column:0002_plugin_rename
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_file:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_auto__add_field_file_target.
 > djangocms_file:0001_initial
   (faked)
 > djangocms_file:0002_auto__add_field_file_target
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_flash:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > djangocms_flash:0001_initial
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_googlemap:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > djangocms_googlemap:0001_initial
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_inherit:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > djangocms_inherit:0001_initial
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_link:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_auto__add_field_link_anchor__chg_field_link_page_link.
 > djangocms_link:0001_initial
   (faked)
 > djangocms_link:0002_auto__add_field_link_phone
   (faked)
 > djangocms_link:0003_auto__add_field_link_anchor__chg_field_link_page_link
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_picture:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > djangocms_picture:0001_initial
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_teaser:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > djangocms_teaser:0001_initial
   (faked)
Running migrations for djangocms_video:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > djangocms_video:0001_initial
   (faked)
Running migrations for reversion:
 - Migrating forwards to 0007_auto__del_field_version_type.
 > reversion:0001_initial
   (faked)
 > reversion:0002_auto__add_field_version_type
   (faked)
 > reversion:0003_auto__add_field_version_object_id_int
   (faked)
 > reversion:0004_populate_object_id_int
   (faked)
 > reversion:0005_auto__add_field_revision_manager_slug
   (faked)
 > reversion:0006_remove_delete_revisions
   (faked)
 > reversion:0007_auto__del_field_version_type
   (faked)


Creating admin user
Username (leave blank to use 'root'): dilshad
Email address: dilshad"gmail.com
Error: Enter a valid email address.
Email address: dilshad@gmail.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.
All done!
Get into '.' directory and type 'python manage.py runserver' to start your project
(env)dilshad@DilVB:~/Desktop/sample/env$ ls
bin  include  lib  local  manage.py  mysite  project.db  static
(env)dilshad@DilVB:~/Desktop/sample/env$ sudo python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
August 27, 2014 - 17:25:09
Django version 1.6.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

[image]
[image]